# Timestamp field can only by updated via behavior in Yii

Tags: mysql, datetime, yii, timestamp

In my model, I have a field named `timestamp` (MySQL type: `timestamp`) defined in `safe` validator and I'm unable to write it manually. Each time I call:

```
$model->timestmap = time();
$model->save();
```

model is saved (row created / updated), that is -- it passes validation without errors, but `timestamp` field is filled with default value of `0000-00-00 00:00:00` (I decided to remove default `on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` attribute, I don't want MySQL to handle this).

However, when I remove above code and attach [`CTimestampBehavior`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CTimestampBehavior) instead, field is being filled with correct values on both update and create, without any problems.

What can be happening or what am I missing? How can behavior update field without problems, while my manual attempt fails? Is this because column type is `timestamp`, not `datetime` or `int`?

I was always told, that first clue, why some attribute isn't saved, is because it is not listed among `safe` validator list or because it is listed on `unsafe` validator list. But this one is listed on `safe` list.

Comment: Thanks everyone for enlightening answers and pity, that I can accept only one of them. I decided to go ahead with `CTimestampBehavior` as an easiest solution in my case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your database field is a [`datetime`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html) field (i assume, looking at your default value), but your filling it with a [unix timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). Try it with an [`CDbExpression`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbExpression) instead:

```
$model->timestamp = new CDbExpression('NOW()');
$model->save();
```

Comment: I always use CDbExpression. +1

Answer (score 2):

I usually use `$model->timestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s')`, it works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers already suggested:

The timestamp needs to be converted into a MySQL compatible date format string somehow upon saving and the other way around when loading. Now you already discovered that the `CTimestampBehavior` does this for you but unfortunately it doesn't care about loading. 
IMO the best solution for you is something along the way of:

```
public function beforeSave()
{
   $this->timestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $this->timestamp);
   return parent::beforeSave();
}

public function afterSave()
{
   // Turn it back into a unix timestamp in case you want to continue working with the record
   $this->timestamp = CDateTimeParser::parse($this->timestamp, 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss');
   parent::afterSave();
}

public function afterFind()
{
   $this->timestamp = CDateTimeParser::parse($this->timestamp, 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss');
   return parent::afterFind();
}
```

It's a lot of work for a stupid timestamp and so for myself I have an auto type conversion behaviour that I link to my models. This behaviour uses the table metadata to take care of everything automatically. Might be a good idea to invest in that. I've thought about making mine open source but it's a bit of a mess atm ;)

But the code above will give you unix times to work with during executing and whilst saving it will temporary convert into a mysql datetime string

Hope that helps.

Comment: +1 for `CDateTimeParser`. Does Yii have class for everything? :]

Comment: I've been using the framework for nearly 5 years and I still discover new stuff every couple of days ;)